# Translation of "Bei dieser Vorlage"

Tags: translation, german-to-english

how would you translate the sentence "Bei der/dieser Vorlage" into the English language? It is commonly said after a response to something. For example:

Person A: *Says something*
Person B: *Cracks a joke about it*. Tut mir leid, aber bei der Vorlage.

Comment: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1057/does-my-translation-request-belong-here-and-if-not-where-and-how-shall-i-ask-it

Comment: Boils down to <SCNR>

Comment: @phipsgabler - I don't think the translation rule is applicable here, it's an idiom, not a selection of text. It seems doubtful a dictionary would help either.

Answer (score 2):

It's a term derived from football (soccer) use. Sometimes "Steilvorlage" is used, too.

In football, it means a pass from another player that is so good that it makes it easy for the receiving player to score the goal.

In its figurative sense, it means that one person gives another one a setup that made it easy to crack a joke. Differently from football, the person who gave the "Vorlage" is quite often at the receiving end of the joke.

Comment: This does not answer the question and could possibly lead to wrong results. It merely shifts the question to *try translate that instead*. Another possible interpretation is *Einladung* because *vorlegen* is certainly not limited to football, though in that sense it could older than soccer to say the least. Wouldn't trust the Stammstisch opinion on that.

Comment: @vectory I don't translate into English because this is German Language SE and translations into other languages would be offtopic, so all I do is explain the German idiom. See the discussion and my answer here: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/sind-fragen-nach-%c3%9cbersetzungen-vom-deutschen-ins-englische-off-topic

Comment: as @RDBury argued, on point translations are on-topic. And as I have argued, you haven't given any, not in the source language not anyhow.

Comment: also, your second most upvoted answer does give an English translation, so you are foul of cheat.

Comment: Either the OP washed to understand the expression, then this answers it. Or the OP already understood the expression and really just wanted an English translation. In that case the question was off-topic. In short, nothing wrong with this answer.